# How to keep keep IText editable once copy/pasted on FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to copy/paste objects with FabricJS, the issue is that when I copy and paste an I text it becomes uneditable and I'd like to make it editable.

here is the JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7Hsdh/11/

**Javascript :**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');

// adding text on canvas
var text = new fabric.Text('Normal Uneditable Text', { 
  left: 100, 
  top: 150,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontSize: 15,
  fill: '#333'
});
canvas.add(text);

var text = new fabric.IText('IText : not editable anymore once copy/pasted why?', { 
  left: 10, 
  top: 50,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontSize: 20,
  fill: '#333'
});
canvas.add(text);


canvas.renderAll();


createListenersKeyboard();
function createListenersKeyboard() {
    document.onkeydown = onKeyDownHandler;
}

function onKeyDownHandler(event) {
    var key;
    if(window.event){
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else{
        key = event.keyCode;
    }

    switch(key){
        case 67: // Ctrl+C
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    copy();
                }
            break;
        case 86: // Ctrl+V
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    paste();
                }
            break;

        default:
            // TODO
            break;
    }
}

var copiedObject,
copiedObjects = new Array();
function copy(){
    copiedObjects = new Array();
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()){
        canvas.getActiveGroup().getObjects().forEach(function(o){
            var object = fabric.util.object.clone(o);
            copiedObjects.push(object);
        });             
    }
    else if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
        var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
        copiedObject = object;
        copiedObjects = new Array();
    }
}

function paste(){
    if(copiedObjects.length > 0){
        for(var i in copiedObjects){
            copiedObjects[i]=fabric.util.object.clone(copiedObjects[i]);
          copiedObjects[i].set("top", copiedObjects[i].top+100);
          copiedObjects[i].set("left", copiedObjects[i].left+100);
          canvas.add(copiedObjects[i]);
          canvas.item(canvas.size() - 1).hasControls = true;
        }                
    }
    else if(copiedObject){
        copiedObject= fabric.util.object.clone(copiedObject);
          copiedObject.set("top", 10);
        copiedObject.set("left", 10);
      canvas.add(copiedObject);
      canvas.item(canvas.size() - 1).hasControls = true;
    }
    canvas.renderAll();  
}
```

Where is the issue and how can I resolve it so I can also copy/paste Itext and keep it as it is instead of turning it to simple text?

Comment: please check the alternative answer. fabric.util.object.clone should not be used in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging into the FabricJS code, I can't answer "why" (which I guess is part of your question) - but I'm sure you could dig into the FabricJS code on your own if you really wanted too know.

However, here's a tweak to your code to get it working for you:

```
function paste() {
  if (copiedObjects.length > 0) {
    for (var i in copiedObjects) {
      if (/text/.test(copiedObjects[i].type)) {
        canvas.add(new fabric.IText(copiedObjects[i].text, {
          left: copiedObjects[i].left + 100,
          top: copiedObjects[i].top + 100,
          fontFamily: copiedObjects[i].fontFamily,
          fontSize: copiedObjects[i].fontSize,
          fill: copiedObjects[i].fill
        }));
      } else {
        copiedObjects[i] = fabric.util.object.clone(copiedObjects[i]);
        copiedObjects[i].set("top", copiedObjects[i].top + 100);
        copiedObjects[i].set("left", copiedObjects[i].left + 100);
        canvas.add(copiedObjects[i]);
      }
      canvas.item(canvas.size() - 1).hasControls = true;
    }
  } else if (copiedObject) {
    if (/text/.test(copiedObject.type)) {
      canvas.add(new fabric.IText(copiedObject.text, {
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        fontFamily: copiedObject.fontFamily,
        fontSize: copiedObject.fontSize,
        fill: copiedObject.fill
      }));
    } else {
      copiedObject = fabric.util.object.clone(copiedObject);
      copiedObject.set("top", 10);
      copiedObject.set("left", 10);
      canvas.add(copiedObject);
    }
    canvas.item(canvas.size() - 1).hasControls = true;
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

My guess, the underlying object behind IText is actually just a plain old Text object with an overlay to make it responsive to keyboard/mouse events.

Here's your JSFiddle updated, http://jsfiddle.net/7Hsdh/13/.

Hope that helps, matey!

Comment: Interesting, but I'm also trying to copy paste image and shapes, so I don't want it to get affected, is there a way to put a condition that say something like if ... = Text or IText, then execute this function ?

Comment: I updated my answer, `/text/.test(object.type))` is what the Kitchen Sink example on FabricJS uses - looking at their code.  Actually, this is the reasoning I used to suspect my observations that IText is actually Text underneath - since they both tested out the same.  Hope it helps, matey!

Comment: No worries.  Happy to help further if I can.   Enjoy life!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong.
the `fabric.util.object.clone` is meant to clone plain javascript objects in a swallow way. Is not meant to copy instances.

You have to use `Object.toObject` to create a copy of your object.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');

var copiedObject,
copiedObjects = new Array();

function copy(){
    copiedObjects = new Array();
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()){
        canvas.getActiveGroup().getObjects().forEach(function(o){
            var object = o.toObject();
            copiedObjects.push(object);
        });             
    }
    else if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
        var object = canvas.getActiveObject().toObject();
        copiedObject = object;
        copiedObjects = new Array();
    }
}

function paste(){
    if(copiedObjects.length > 0){
        for(var i in copiedObjects){
          copiedObjects[i].top += 100;
          copiedObjects[i].left += 100;
          var className = copiedObjects[i].type.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + copiedObjects[i].type.slice(1);
          fabric[className].fromObject(copiedObjects[i], function() {
            canvas.add();
          });
        }                
    }
    else if(copiedObject){
       .... do the same without the the for loop ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Just gived it a try, http://jsfiddle.net/7Hsdh/17/, I can't make it work, did I do something wrong ?

Comment: maybe i did. i will check when i get a chance.